# Resize of shapes at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have this simple drawing of a house, and I want to adapt the roof change its width as the house body changes it width **and/or** the door adapt to the width of the house body. I have been working for hours on any solution but the code that works seems just to complex to implement with beginner project like this. Here is my code. I have tried with some functions that connect the body with mouseLeftButtonDown but it was not working.

```xml
<Window x:Class="LAB2.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">

              <Canvas UseLayoutRounding="True">
                <Rectangle Canvas.Left="86"  Canvas.Top="190" Height="171" Fill="Blue"    Name="body" Stroke="Black" MouseEnter="body_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="body_MouseLeave" Width="395" />
                <Rectangle Canvas.Left="118" Canvas.Top="229" Height="82" Fill="{Binding ElementName=body, Path=Fill}"  Name="window" Stroke="Black" Width="89"/>
                <Rectangle Canvas.Left="346" Canvas.Top="229" Fill="{Binding ElementName=body, Path=Fill}" Height="132"  Name="door" Stroke="Black" Width="83"/>
                <Polygon Points="10,110 230,10 500,110" Fill="{Binding ElementName=body, Path=Fill}" Stroke="Black" Name="triangle" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="86" />
                <Rectangle Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="109" Height="61" Fill="{Binding ElementName=body, Path=Fill}" Name="chimney" Stroke="Black" Width="36" />
                <Button Canvas.Left="491" Canvas.Top="12" Content="Click" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" />
             </Canvas>

</Window>
```

I will be really thankful for any suggestions or guidance with this task.

Comment: First of all if you do have some code, you should provide it to us. Second of all I already answered your previous question about this house project. It has easy solution, it also can be done using only xaml code, but you should try harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is your solution... I used simple triggers again.

```xml
<Control>
        <Control.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    <Grid x:Name="HouseBody" Height="153" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="78" Canvas.Top="159">
                        <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="Blue" x:Name="body" Stroke="Black" Width="Auto"/>
                        <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="Blue"  x:Name="window" Stroke="Black" Width="89" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,17,0,54"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="Auto"  x:Name="door" Stroke="Black" Width="Auto" Margin="235.5,17,25.5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="HouseRoof" Height="131.5" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="77" Canvas.Top="27.5">
                        <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="Blue" x:Name="chimney" Stroke="Black" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="44.066,22.965,265.934,8" />
                        <Path x:Name="path" Data="M74.752528,159.37536 L429.11068,159.37578 242,26.5 z" Fill="Blue" Height="Auto" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Width="Auto" Margin="0.25,0,-2.589,-0.865"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Canvas>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="body" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="window" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="door" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="path" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="chimney" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="HouseBody" Value="395"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="HouseRoof" Value="395"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="body" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        <Setter TargetName="window" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        <Setter TargetName="door" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        <Setter TargetName="triangle" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>-->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>     
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Control.Template>
    </Control>
```

only big change is that I substituted polygon with Path. Hope I helped. You can do the same with StoryBoards and of course using codeBehind and C# when you group your objects into  named grids it's much more easy. you only set grids Width and its done.

It would be like this:

XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Canvas MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <Grid x:Name="HouseBody" Height="153" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="78" Canvas.Top="159">
            <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="Blue" x:Name="body" Stroke="Black" Width="Auto"/>
            <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="Blue"  x:Name="window" Stroke="Black" Width="89" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,17,0,54"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="Auto"  x:Name="door" Stroke="Black" Width="Auto" Margin="235.5,17,25.5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="HouseRoof" Height="131.5" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="77" Canvas.Top="27.5">
            <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="Blue" x:Name="chimney" Stroke="Black" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="44.066,22.965,265.934,8" />
            <Path x:Name="path" Data="M74.752528,159.37536 L429.11068,159.37578 242,26.5 z" Fill="Blue" Height="Auto" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Width="Auto" Margin="0.25,0,-2.589,-0.865"/>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

And CodeBehind:

```
    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        HouseBody.Width = 400;
        HouseRoof.Width = 400;
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        HouseBody.Width = 350;
        HouseRoof.Width = 350;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I managed to write a function with GridSplitter but your suggestions was also useful